# eloquent scope to eager load with constriant?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Ok so I'm trying to setup a scope that will restrict which users are returned based on a column in a hasOne relation.

Here are the two methods from my User model:

```
public function scopeHasImage($query)
{
    return $query->with(['profile' => function($query){
        $query->where('avatar', '!=', '');
    }]);
}

public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

When I call it like so:

```
$users = User::HasImage()->simplePaginate(15);
```

All of that works ok untill I go to display the code in my blade template like so:

```
            @foreach($users as $user)
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                <a href="{{ route('user.profile.public', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ $user->profile->avatar }}" />
                </a>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

That results in this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I have dumped the $user->profile and it is an object which has attributes listed and one of those attributes is avatar. So I'm not sure why this is not working.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to identify on which line error occurs?

Comment: The error is generated by {{ $user->profile->avatar }} in the blade template. If I remove that code it loads every thing as it should.

Comment: Try dumping `$users` instead of `$user->profile` to confirm if everyone have required properties. Can you also show us where and how you do eager loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly one of your users has no profile attached. Because you probably dumped only the the first `$user->profile` you didn't see that...

You can fix this by wrapping it in an if:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @if($profile = $user->profile)
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <a href="{{ route('user.profile.public', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ $profile->avatar }}" />
            </a>
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Or exclude users without a profile in the first place (which is probably what you wanted all along)

```
public function scopeHasImage($query)
{
    return $query->with('profile')->whereHas('profile', function($query){
        $query->where('avatar', '!=', '');
    });
}
```

Comment: Your scope has fixed my issue. Why did you use ->with() with ->whereHas? I assumed that restricting the ->with() would restrict it to only users with profiles who's avatar was set. I guess that just returns all users and some may have attached profiles if they have an avatar.

Comment: `with()` is to load a relationship. `has()` to restrict the model you load based on if it has a certain relation. `with()` with a closure and `whereHas()` do the same but let you filter the related model. What you where doing was eager loading only profiles that had an avatar, instead of restricting the resulting collection. My answer still uses `with()` because otherwise Eloquent will run a db query for every user's profile you access.